Narrow no-break space not functioning in Firefox?
My question is related to this post : How to render narrow non-breaking spaces in HTML for Windows?
According to a 2021 addendum, the NNBSP   character should be correctly rendered in "all major browsers" since 2021.
That would be great because in French typography we need a thin space that is not breakable.
I tested it in many different browsers but it still seems to not exist in Firefox 128 on a Mac. Actually I also tested the thin space ( ) which does not work either.
I cannot comment the aforementioned commentary so here is my question: is it a well-known issue? Has Firefox ever correctly displayed a non-breaking narrow space? Or should I stick to whatever I hack I can think of to try and render it in Firefox?
I've been searching the WWW about this issue for more than 10 years now.   should be the answer but if Firefox does not implement it, that is a big issue (even though FF's market shares have dropped to near zero in the past decade, I feel like I should still consider it an issue).
I built an HTML page with the same sentence in French using different kinds of spaces, but two of them (  and  ) do not show at all in Firefox 128.
Here is the code, feel free to resize your window to break the yellow spaces.
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="fr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Guillemets et espaces fines</title>
    <style>
        /* RESET */
        h1, h2, h3, p, ul, ol, li {
            margin: 0;
            line-height: 1.25;
        }

        body {
            color: #333;
            text-align: left;
            background-color: silver;
            hyphens: auto;
            text-align: left;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 2.6em;
            font-weight: 100;
            color: black;
            line-height: 1.1;
        }

        h1, h2 {
            margin-top: 1em;
            margin-bottom: .5em;
        }

        p {
            margin-bottom: .75em;
        }
        /* \0020 = espace (normale, sécable)
           \00A0 = espace insécable (&nbsp;)
           \2009 = espace fine (thin space, sécable)
           \200A = espace ultrafine (hair space, sécable) 
           \2060 = word joiner (empêche qu'une espace sécable soit sécable ? Nope, marche pas) */

        q {
            quotes: '«\2009\2060' '\2009»' '“' '”';
        }

        small {
            font-size: .5em;
        }

        span {
            background: gold;
        }
        .bug {
            background: darkred;
            padding: .5em 1em .25em;
            color: pink;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }




    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Au sujet du match des Diables rouges<span>&#8239;</span>: «<span>&#8239;</span>Ce n’est pas contre la France qu’on a perdu l’Euro<span>&#8239;</span>» <small>(Espace fine insécable #8239)</small></h1>
    <p>L’espace fine insécable (&amp;#8239;) n’existe pas dans toutes les polices et elle n’est malheureusement pas compatible avec tous les navigateurs.</p>
    <p class="bug">Ne fonctionne pas sous Firefox (testé sur FF v.128)</p>
    <h1>Au sujet du match des Diables rouges<span> </span>: «<span> </span>Ce n’est pas contre la France qu’on a perdu l’Euro<span> </span>» <small>(Espace normale)</small></h1>
    <p>L’espace standard (sécable) disparaît quand le caractère qui la suit passe à la ligne.<br>Les guillemets peuvent alors se retrouver isolés en fin de ligne ou en début de ligne.</p>
    <h1>Au sujet du match des Diables rouges<span>&nbsp;</span>: «<span>&nbsp;</span>Ce n’est pas contre la France qu’on a perdu l’Euro<span>&nbsp;</span>» <small>(HTML nbsp)</small></h1>
    <p>L’espace insécable a l’inconvénient d’être plus large qu'une espace fine.</p>

    <h1>Au sujet du match des Diables rouges<span>&thinsp;</span>: «<span>&thinsp;</span>Ce n’est pas contre la France qu’on a perdu l’Euro<span>&thinsp;</span>» <small>(HTML Thin Space)</small></h1>
    <p>Contrairement à l'espace standard, l'espace fine (Thin Space) ne disparaît pas quand le caractère qui la suit passe à la ligne.<br>L'espace fine (Thin Space) reste collée au caractère <strong>précédent</strong>.<br>Le guillemet fermant reste collé au signe précédent (y compris Thin Space).<br>Donc, en théorie, les guillemets français <strong>fermants</strong> précédés de l'espace fine restent attachés au caractère qui précède l'espace fine (à tester dans tous les navigateurs).</p>
    <p class="bug">Ne fonctionne pas sous Firefox (testé sur FF v.128)</p>

    <h1>Au sujet du match des Diables rouges<span>&thinsp;&NoBreak;</span>: «<span>&thinsp;&NoBreak;</span>Ce n’est pas contre la France qu’on a perdu l’Euro<span>&thinsp;</span>» <small>(HTML Thin Space + Word Joiner)</small></h1>
    <p>Les guillements fermants précédés de l'espace fine ne posent pas problème (voir ci-dessus).<br>En ce qui concerne les guillemets <em>ouvrants</em>, il faut faire suivre l’espace fine qui suit les guillemets par un caractère spécial «&nbsp;gluon&nbsp;» <em>(Word Joiner)</em>&nbsp;: <code>&amp;NoBreak;</code>.<br>De cette façon, l'espace fine reste attachée non seulement aau caractère qui la précède (les guillemets ouvrants), mais aussi au caractère qui la suit (elle devient donc, <i lang="la">de facto</i>, insécable).</p>
    <p class="bug">Ne fonctionne pas sous Firefox (testé sur FF v.128)</p>

    <h1>Au sujet du match des Diables rouges&nbsp;: <q>Ce n’est pas contre la France qu’on a perdu l’Euro</q> <small>(CSS Thin Space + Word Joiner)</small></h1>
    <p>En CSS,<br>
        <code>\2009</code> correspond à l’espace fine <em>(Thin Space)</em><br>
        <code>\2060</code> correspond au gluon <em>(Word Joiner)</em>.
    </p>
    <p class="bug">Ne fonctionne pas sous Firefox (testé sur FF v.128)</p>
  </body>

</html>


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Done. How about an answer now? :-)
